# Jquery-rails stopped working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, archlinux

I was running some rails app on my Arch system. I updated it lastly and developed some stuff, but my rails apps where untouched. Today I test them and suddenly jquery has stopped working.

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on every single page using jquery.
However, in the app log I can read:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for ...
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (5ms)
```

So I get application.js is loading ok.

Then in application.js y have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I guess everything is correctly setup, it was working earlier, so now there must be some sort of incompatibility, there is some info about my setup:

```
$ gem list | grep jquery
jquery-rails (2.2.1, 2.1.4, 2.1.3)

$ cat Gemfile | grep jquery
gem 'jquery-rails'

$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.8

$ uname -a
Linux nosferatu 3.8.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 29 20:45:06 CET 2013 i686 GNU/Linux
```

What can be wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoanswer:
The solution for me was manually setting the lastest ruby version on Gemfile and then executing bundle update.

Peace